# Where is the output of debug!() calls in Meilisearch?

Tags: logging, rust, meilisearch

Trying to understand an [open source project](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch) and I have seen the following code in many places

```
debug!("called with params: {:?}", body); // or some parameter instead of bo
```

when I run `cargo run` I do not see any of these outputs in the console. only the `INFO` logs are displayed

```
[2022-12-19T13:53:23Z INFO  actix_server::builder] Starting 8 workers
[2022-12-19T13:53:23Z INFO  actix_server::server] Actix runtime found; starting in Actix runtime
[2022-12-19T14:00:58Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] ::1 "GET /stats HTTP/1.1" 200 49 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.009129
[2022-12-
```

I tried running `RUST_LOG=debug cargo run`. but still unable to see the debug output. as I can see the logging is configured via `rust-log` crate. but with my limited experience with rust I couldn't figure out more. I assume these debug logs are in some file but not sure exactly where they are.

Comment: [There's an option in `struct Opt` called `log_level`](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch/blob/867279f2a45e805bcee0e0fd5865f25a7a03c6fd/meilisearch/src/option.rs#L231), so I assume that the log level can be set by a command line option. The field `log_level` is [used in `main.rs` here](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch/blob/867279f2a45e805bcee0e0fd5865f25a7a03c6fd/meilisearch/src/main.rs#L19) as the filter.

Comment: Great, I found it `cargo run -- --log-level=debug` started outputting debug logs. If you can write an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meilisearch` provides a command line option `--log-level=...` for users to specify the log level, which can contain any filter string that's accepted by the `env_logger` crate. To enable all the `log::debug!` outputs, supply `--log-level=debug` when running the binary.

```bash
# If building from source
cargo run -- --log-level=debug

# If installed
meilisearch --log-level=debug
```

See [the documentation of `env_logger`](https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/index.html#enabling-logging) for the syntax of filter strings.